# How do I set the pop-up time properly in Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using Eonasdan DateTimePicker using the time part separate form the date part. The code to set it up looks like this:

```
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    stepping: 5,
    format: 'hh:ss A',
    widgetPositioning: {
        vertical: 'bottom'
    },
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
});
```

My invoking code is:

```
$('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").date(moment("01:35 PM", "hh:mm A"));
```

The moment parameters are set because I clicked on 1:35 PM in my calendar and the popup loaded with these values. So far so good.

But when I click on the little clock icon to bring up the picker, the time jumps to 04:35 AM every time. The minutes are preserved but the hour and AM/PM are not. No matter what time on my calendar I pick, the time shows properly in my form field but the picker popup jumps to 4 for hours and PM. I am guessing there is something weird with moment not understanding the formats or something? Are my moment format strings proper? I run this in 24-hour time mode and have a similar problem except the AM/PM is missing.

Thanks in advance for any hints on what went wrong.

Comment: Turns out it was a version issue. I had updated to the latest version, 4.17.37 but when I rolled back to 4.15.35 it started working again. I am going to guess this is a dependency issue, not a bug in the new version. Does anyone else have confirmation?

Comment: Can you please put a fiddle like with JsFiddle as am unable to reproduce it on current version. As a side note `format: 'hh:ss A',` why here is seconds and then later is minutes here `hh:mm A`?

Comment: the ss vs mm is js vs moment syntax. I am still trying to figure out what I didn't update as I think I had only updated the js file.

Comment: Yes, this is a version thing upgrade to the last one, but what I said before is that in oune your're using seconds and then on other you're using minutos with moment.js syntax, the stepping wil NOT work with seconds

Comment: Typo. It should have been ii and mm. Sorry. Thanks for the catch!